# Get data from multiple input boxes in polymer

Tags: jquery, polymer, 2-way-object-databinding, paper-elements

I have a list of "card" element; each one has a paper input element and a button element; each element takes some datas from an external JSON (in the my-post-service element I have a core-ajax embedded). My goal is that, when user writes something in a text box and clicks in the relative button, infos of the specific card and text inserted by user are sent to another function. 
Here is the code of this polymer element:

```
<polymer-element name="template-list">
<template>
    <my-post-service id="service" posts="{{posts}}" url="http://localhost:9111/v3/objects/templates">
    </my-post-service>
    <div id="pcId" layout horizontal wrap>
        <template repeat="{{post in posts}}">
            <my-post-card>
                <img src="http://localhost:9111/v3/resources/{{post.representation[0].icon}}" width="70" height="70">
                <h2>{{post.name}}</h2>
                <p>{{post.description}}</p>
                <paper-input name="paper-input" id="paperInputId" inputValue="{{value}}" label="Insert new object name..." floatingLabel="false"></paper-input>
                <add-object-button on-click="{{fetchName}}" template="{{post.name}}" name="{{objName}}"></add-object-button>
            </my-post-card>
        </template>

    </div>
    <style>
        :host {
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
        }
        my-post-card {
            margin-bottom: 30px;
        }
    </style>
</template>

<script>

    var objName;

    Polymer({
        fetchName: function () {
            objName = this.$.pcId.querySelector('#paperInputId').value;
        },
        get objName() {
            return objName;
        },
    });
</script>
```

At the moment, when I click on some button, I'm always able to get specific card infos (through template attribute) but I can only retrieve text from the first paper input element (the one of the first card).

Ps I'm new on polymer so maybe I'm missing something stupid...!

Answer (score 0):

```
objName = this.$.pcId.querySelectorAll('paper-input').value;
```

i think is what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes, I already tried...but with querySelectorAll it doesn't work (I get an "undefined" value from all text box)...

Comment: made a Plunker to show what i have come up with. querySelectorAll will get all the elements but doesn't get the values. so you can get a array of elements and parse through them and get the value from each one.   http://plnkr.co/edit/u6shXfgMlUP3UykvLQr7?p=preview

Comment: Hi jimi, I have solved this problem moving the script part into the <my-post-card> template (here the code for the two elements, if you are interested: http://plnkr.co/edit/YXw34FlaKke5imdDi3om?p=preview). Thank for your help.